# Rails::Generator is not creating factory in spec folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rails-generators

I am trying to generate a new factory inside a module and I basically required

```
require 'rails/generators'
```

and I am calling the command below. Notice that it creates the file inside the **test folder**.

```
Rails::Generators.invoke 'factory_girl:model', ["Audit"]

-- create_table("audit", {:id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0085s
      create  test/factories/audit.rb
```

When I try to generate the factory in the terminal, it creates the factory inside the **spec folder**:

```
vo@so:~/Desktop/ruby-pos/api$ rails generate factory_girl:model 'Audit'
      create  spec/factories/audits.rb
```

My problem is: I basically want to create the factory inside the **spec folder** when I run `Rails::Generators.invoke 'factory_girl:model', ["Audit"]`.

I have been stuck in this problem for a few hours and that's why I am here :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you didn't specify directory for factories in your `application.rb` try to add this. Must help.

**UPDATE (good point from equivalent8):**

For FactoryBot gem:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```

For older FactoryGirl gem:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```

Comment: `g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: 'spec/factories'`